# Mutating API property to contain key to be iterable in for:each

Tags: lightning-web-components

How can I pass an array of strings (errors) into a separate child component (c-component-errors), and be able to show a toast for each one by iterating them using <template for:each...

My issue is that <template for:each requires the first child to have a key attribute with a unique identifier. How do I add this key to the data structure of each error, now that the initial data structure is just an array of strings?

A workaround could of course be to prepare the data structure before updating/setting the "errors" property, but I want to have the componentErrors component to be easily reusable.

## Parent.html

```
<c-component-errors errors={errors}></c-component-errors>
```

## Parent.js

```
@track errors;
...
.catch(error => {
   this.errors.push(...reduceErrors(error)); //using reduceErrors from the ldsUtils here
});
```

## componentErrors.html

```
<template for:each{errors} for:item="error">
   <div key={error.key}>{error.message}</div>
</template>
```

## componentErrors.js

```
@api errors;
```

Comment: `My issue is that <template for:each requires the first child to have a key attribute with a unique identifier.` Is this a functional or design requirement for you?

Comment: we are iterating errors. We are not sure whether the error has a key with **Key** or not.   Can you try <div key={error}>{error.message}</div>

Comment: Also, why are you doing this `<div key={error.key}>{error.message}</div>` when you want to display toast?

Comment: @arut it's a design requirement. I could easily make this work by making sure the data I pass to the component has both a key and a message.

Comment: & do you already have requirement/ logic for unique key generation at your end?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're passing an array of string to `componentErrors`, but in its for:each you're requiring an array of elements with `key` and `message` properites, so it should not work.
Anyway if you have an array, you always have an unique key for each element: its index.
So you could map your original array of string into an array of element with key and message. You don't need to do it before passing the array to the child component, you can do it in the child component itself providing a getter and a setter.

```js
_errors;

@api
set errors(errorList) {
    this._errors = errorList.map((message, key) => {
        return {
            key,
            message
        };
    });
}

get errors() {
    return this._errors;
}
```

By the way, there is a typo in `componentErrors.html`, there is a missing `=` after the for:each

```
<template for:each={errors} for:item="error">
   <div key={error.key}>{error.message}</div>
</template>
```

---

Edit:
If you setted `errors` on the child component only when it's added to the dom

```html
<c-component-errors errors={errors}></c-component-errors>
```

It won't get automatically updated when parent's `errors` changes. You have to explicit set it:

```js
...
.catch(error => {
   this.errors.push(...reduceErrors(error)); //using reduceErrors from the ldsUtils here
   // You should either explicitly set the property on child
   const componentErrors = this.template.querySelector('c-component-errors');
   componentErrors.errors = this.errors;
   // Or change the reference of the parent's property
   // this.errors = [...this.errors];
});
```

Comment: I should have made it more clear, that this was not a real example. It was only to allow for a discussion around how to pass a string array to the component, and then have it mutate that into an array of a complex type with both message and key in it.

Comment: I tried creating a setter as you suggest, but it won't get called once the value of the string array changes from the parent. How do I make sure that it does?

Comment: @Andreas86 `.map()` creates a new array, so every time the original ones changes, the parent must pass it to the child component. [Here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.events_create_dispatch#events_create_dispatch__pass_data) Salesforce suggest to send only primitives (not your case), or to copy data to a new object before passing it between components, that's what `map()` does. "Copying the data to a new object ensures that you’re sending only the data you want, and that the receiver can’t mutate your data."

Comment: Hmm.. are you suggesting creating a new object on the parent side or the child side? because I don't see the child setter ever getting called when the parent changes its errors property

Comment: @Andreas86 I updated the answer. If that's not how you really pass the array to the child component, could you please share your code? Including both when the array is passed to the child and when the parent changes it.

Comment: Thank you. That is exactly how I do it, and now we're at the core of it: Do I really need to explicitly set the value on the component when it changes? My intuition would be that it did that automatically via the framework?

Comment: @Andreas86 Since `error` is not a primitive, you should either explicitly set it on child component or change its reference, i.e. `this.errors = [...this.errors];`. I've added this point to the answer